# How to get the center point of a shape like polygon use KonvaJs plugin?

Tags: konvajs

How can I get the center point of a shape like polygon use konva?
I need to add some text label to the center of a shape.

Comment: Thank you very mush. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `shape.getClientRect()` to get bounding client rectangle of the shape.

Then absolute position of the center will be:

```
const box = shape.getClientRect();
const x = box.x + box.width / 2;
const y = box.y + box.height / 2;
```